# Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains - trying to setup HTTPS in virtual localhost on docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ssl-certificate, traefik

I am trying to setup a certificate for a locally running react app on a virtual host `local.example.com`. This has to just work locally on docker setup. After going through some articles, I came up with this docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - mongodbdata:/data/db
    networks:
      - proxy
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    networks:
      - proxy
  react:
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    stdin_open: true
    volumes:
      - ./client:/client
      - /client/node_modules
    labels:
      # this enables traefik for your service
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      # this defines the url, traefik will get the ssl certificate for
      - "traefik.http.routers.myapplication.rule=Host(`local.example.com`)"
      # this tells traefik to use https to access the website
      - "traefik.http.routers.myapplication.entrypoints=websecure"
      # this tells traefik to use the certresolver, that we defined above for resolving tls (in our case letsencrypt)
      - "traefik.http.routers.myapplication.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
      # this let's us forward the port we set above. Change this to the port you expose in your application (3000, 4000, ...) or remove the line, if your application already exposes port 80/443
      - "traefik.http.services.myapplication.loadbalancer.server.port=3000"
    depends_on:
      - "server"
    networks:
      - proxy
  server:
    build:
      context: ./server
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "5001:5001"
    volumes:
      - traefik.toml:/traefik.toml
      - acme.json:/acme.json
      - ./server:/server
      - /server/node_modules
    labels:
      # this enables traefik for your service
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      # this defines the url, traefik will get the ssl certificate for
      - "traefik.http.routers.myapplication.rule=Host(`local.example.com`)"
      # this tells traefik to use https to access the website
      - "traefik.http.routers.myapplication.entrypoints=websecure"
      # this tells traefik to use the certresolver, that we defined above for resolving tls (in our case letsencrypt)
      - "traefik.http.routers.myapplication.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
      # this let's us forward the port we set above. Change this to the port you expose in your application (3000, 4000, ...) or remove the line, if your application already exposes port 80/443
      - "traefik.http.services.myapplication.loadbalancer.server.port=5001"
    depends_on:
      - "mongo"
    networks:
      - proxy
  whoami:
    image: "containous/whoami"
    container_name: "myapplication"
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "4000:4000"
    networks:
      - proxy

  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.2"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      # this can be uncommented to get more information, in case something doesn't work
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      # set this to true to get access to the traefik web interface unter http://YOURIP:8080
      - "--api.insecure=false"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=true"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge=true"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
        #- "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory" # uncomment this line to only test ssl generation first (to make sure you don't run into letsencrypt limits)
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=kamlekar.venkatesh@gmail.com"
      - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8080:8080" # this is used for the web interface, that let's you check and monitor traefik and your configuration. It's very nice for debugging your config - only available if "api.insecure" above is set to true
    volumes:
      - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    networks:
      - proxy
    # The following is only necessary if you want to enforce https!
    # if you don't need that, you can just remove the labels here
    labels:
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.rule=hostregexp(`{host:.+}`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.http-catchall.middlewares=redirect-to-https"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true

volumes:
  mongodbdata:
  traefik.toml:
  acme.json:
```

On doing `docker-compose up`, I am seeing the following error in `traefik` service. Also, though the react app service is running in docker but I hit `https://local.example.com:3001`, is unreachable

> time="2022-01-23T08:30:52Z" level=error msg="Unable to obtain ACME certificate for domains "local.example.com": unable to generate a certificate for the domains [local.example.com]: error: one or more domains had a problem:\n[local.example.com] acme: error: 400 :: urn:ietf:params:acme:error:dns :: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for local.example.com - check that a DNS record exists for this domain; DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up AAAA for local.example.com - check that a DNS record exists for this domain, url: \n" providerName=myresolver.acme routerName=myapplication@docker rule="Host(`local.example.com`)"

Here are the [research notes](https://gist.github.com/kamlekar/f962dbc80f4b02b078864a476688b813) which I tried till now (These notes for only my personal understanding so could be not in detail)

You can start from this fiddle: https://github.com/kamlekar/react-docker-ssl-virtualhost

Comment: So, does a A or AAAA record for `local.example.com` exist? (seemingly not, as the error suggests) And once you have it, make sure the IP Adress it is pointing to is reachable from the public and has a HTTP Service listening on port 80 ...

Comment: Do you own `example.com` ? Is it accessible from outside of your network ? Did you create a DNS entry that points to the `local` subdomain and will end up calling your traeffik reverse proxy ? <= those questions are obviously rhetoric ones => You need a domain and let's encrypt must be able to join it to get and ACME cert.

Comment: I am trying to run this locally. I don't want it to have a IP address. It just mapping of https://localhost to `https://local.example.com`.

Comment: Then you cannot get a let's encrypt ACME cert, unles you create you own ACME capable service that you will install on your own local network.

Comment: Looks like I am doing this quite wrong then. I am trying to run virtual host on https locally.

Comment: Create a self signed cert and install it directly. That's more than enough for a local test.

Comment: Do you own `example.com`? If yes, you can also create a certificate via "DNS Challenge", you won't need a public IP or server for that. And if its just for your local network, create a self-signed certificate

Comment: https://www.khatastroffik.net/self-signed-certificates/

Comment: Mr_Green you can’t get a public Certificate for a private setup, because the validation is done from the certificate authority over the public web. They don’t have access to your private network. You need a self-signed certificate as @Zeitounator mentioned.

Comment: Show me your traefik.toml file, please.

Comment: @AlekseyVaganov I don't have it. I think I can't do this using traefik or letsencrypt because I am trying to run locally. I am looking into docker nginx currently.

Comment: @Mr_Green, check out the other StackOverflow thread I provided in my answer. You can totally use self-signed certificates in Traefik in a docker-compose setup. You just need to create the certificates, edit the traefik config file and mount them all into the container.

Comment: Thanks, @theUndying I tried all this stuff but seems because I am not into networking or DevOps I am messing up somewhere and getting stuck in multiple different efforts. Appreciate it if anyone could provide a working solution rather than a theoretical explanation which evidently I am failing to understand. Bounty is my desperate attempt here.

Comment: @Mr_Green check my updated answer, I gave an example with nginx and openssl. I think that's minimal enough and should do the job. Just comment under it, if you have any questions and I'll try to answer them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use TLS for your local setup. The host you need a certificate for is `local.example.com`. There is no way to obtain a certificate from `Letsencrypt` for this name, because you're not controlling the `example.com` domain. One of the ways `Letsencrypt` creates a certificate is a challenge - you prove that you own the domain by creating a [TXT DNS record](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#dns-01-challenge). If you own a domain you can do that, but your case is different, because you only need this for local development.

However, you can just use `openssl` to generate a self signed certificate for whichever domain name you want. [This is a good reference on how to do this.](https://www.baeldung.com/openssl-self-signed-cert) You can use the `local.example.com` domain name for the generated certificate. If you're successful, you'll end up with the certificate and it's private key. Note where you save those files, as you'll need them. Keep in mind that the certificate is self-signed, so your browser will give you a warning, unless you add this certificate to the trust store of your operating system.

The next step in your case is to make Traefik use those self signed certificates when serving content from your application. I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60072381/16198415) has a good example of that.

After having this, you'll only need to [edit your hosts file](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/) and redirect your `localhost:8080` (the port on which your Traefik serves your application) to `local.example.com`.

Also, Traefik is not the only solution for your case. You can also achieve the same using Nginx, for example. Choose which one satisfies your use case. My suggestion would be to use the one that's easiest to configure, because it's for local development. [Here's the first result I got](https://codingwithmanny.medium.com/configure-self-signed-ssl-for-nginx-docker-from-a-scratch-7c2bcd5478c6) when searching for a `nginx docker-compose self-signed certificate`.

**UPDATE**
Here's a quick example of what I'm describing above.
First generate the certificate:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -sha256 -days 1000 -subj '/CN=local.example.com'
```

You'll end up with two files in your current directory (**key.pem** and **cert.pem**). Now create the **nginx.conf:**

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  local.example.com;

        ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key  key.pem;

        ssl_session_timeout  5m;

        location / {
          proxy_pass               http://myapp:8080;
          proxy_set_header         Host     $host;
          proxy_read_timeout       1800;
          proxy_connect_timeout    1800;
        }
    }
}
```

And now the **docker-compose.yaml** file:

```
version: "3"

services:   
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./cert.pem:/etc/nginx/cert.pem
      - ./key.pem:/etc/nginx/key.pem
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - local-dev-01

  myapp:
    image: your-react-app-image
    command: "command-that-starts-your-app"
    networks:
      - local-dev-01

networks:   
  local-dev-01:
```

Docker creates a network called `local-dev-01` for you, which allows both services to be able to resolve each other by their name. That's why we have **myapp:8080** in the **nginx.conf**. We also mount the configuration and the generated certificate and key for `local.example.com`.
The final step is to edit your `hosts` file and add the following line:

```
127.0.0.1      local.example.com
```

After that, you should have no trouble reaching your application on `https://local.example.com` on your machine. Keep in mind that your browser will keep warning you that the certificate is self-signed, so you should add it as an exception.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer update. can't we add the host through Nginx rather than manually updating the host file which changes for different OS platforms? I was checking this [nginx-proxy](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy) which is promising but I am unable to get any solution yet (still trying). I understand this wasn't mentioned in the question but just a good-to-have thing that I am trying to implement. Any help is appreciated. You can [check here](https://github.com/kamlekar/react-docker-ssl-virtualhost) where I am doing similar as mentioned in your answer which is working fine

Comment: The change in the hosts file is not related to nginx. It's about how your OS resolves the name local.example.com. Since this is a private setup, no public DNS would resolve local.example.com to the IP of your nginx container (same reason you can't create a Letsencrypt certificate). You can avoid the hosts update if you have your own private DNS server where you add a record for local.example.com. Otherwise you can either edit the hosts file or use localhost, but change the "Host: " header you send. As far as Nginx is concerned, it knows it's name is local.example.com and it can resolve "myapp"

Comment: You can see how two servers are defined [here](https://github.com/kamlekar/react-docker-ssl-virtualhost/blob/main/nginx/node.conf). Nginx just knows the name, but does not care how you (the client) resolves them. It will be looking at the "Host: " header you're sending and make a decision where to proxy your request. At least I'm not aware of other solutions for the hosts file situation.